# alter a table column and set identity from max existing in that column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a Column with MaxCode name, in Mytable that filled before,now i want alter this column and set it type to identity that start with max number existing in column MaxCode

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to reset seed value for Identity column

```
DECLARE @newSeed NUMERIC(10)
SELECT @newSeed = MAX(MaxCode) FROM Mytable
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Mytable, RESEED, @newSeed)
```